# Need help understanding this reference

Tags: particle-physics

I need help understandig [this reference](https://www.iaea.org/inis/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/25/024/25024151.pdf):

*Calculation of inelastic mean free path and stopping power for electrons in solid from an optical-data model*, by J.M. Fernandéz-Varea, D. Liljequist, R.Mayol and F.Salvat.

I have to plot the stopping power in terms of the energy of the incident particle. What I do not understand is:

- What is $E$?
- What is $W^\prime$? I undertand this is the resonant energy (it is clearly stated), but where do I find it? Is it tabulated? How could the authors plot the stopping power for silicon? How did they know $W^\prime$?

Comment: The first few pages detail those variables, did you read the reference?

Comment: People are voting you down because page 2 of your reference defines E and W, and to get W’ you only have to read to page 3.

Comment: Please @Triatticus read  my edit.

Comment: Please @BobJacobsen read my edit

Answer (score 1):

It seems all the information are already given there. 
Here if it helps:

What is E? 
[image]

What is W?

[image]

What is $W^\prime$? (Also refer the graph.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: But where do I find the resonance energy $W^\prime$? Is it tabulated?

Comment: @mattiav27 What's on page 8?

Comment: that is how the parameters $A$ and $B$ depend on $W^\prime$ not some tabulated values of $W^\prime$.